# Where is a verb in "a troll out cold with a bloody lump on its head"

Tags: expressions, phrase-meaning

> a troll even larger than the one they had tackled, **out cold with a
> bloody lump on its head**

This is a quote from J.K. Rowling's Harry Potter (emphasis mine). I wonder whether the two words "out cold" is an adjective or "out" is a verb? Sorry I'm really confused how to read this phrase.

Comment: No, but out means not awake, and out cold is very much not awake. With the lump, we know that he is unconscious, not sleeping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole portion you have emphasized is an [adjective phrase](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/example-adjective-clauses.html), an adjective clause with the subject pronoun and verb omitted; here's the full sentence as context for other readers:

> Eyes watering, they saw, flat on the floor in front of them, a troll
> even larger than the one they had tackled, out cold with a bloody lump
> on its head.

You can parse this as "...they saw, ... a troll" and the extra phrases all modify the object "a troll". In the specific case you're interested in, you can imagine adding "which was", so "... they saw, ... a troll ... which was out cold with a bloody lump on its head"

["out cold"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+cold) is a phrase meaning, as the comment suggests, unconscious

Comment: Thank you so much, it was very helpful